# Laravel Store: Best way to store Item options upon checkout

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to build a store and everything is going great. But I'm running into an issue that I'm having trouble wrapping my head around to find the best option.

I have an Item Model:

```
class Item extends \Eloquent implements \Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableInterface
{
    protected $table = 'store_items';

    public function options()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\Dcn\Store\Option', 'store_items_options', 'items_id', 'options_id');
    }
}
```

And an options model:

```
class Option extends \Eloquent implements \Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableInterface
{
    protected $table = 'store_options';

    public function values()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\Dcn\Store\OptionValues', 'store_option_values', 'options_id', 'op-values_id');
    }
}
```

And an OptionValues Model:

```
class OptionValues extends \Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'store_op-values';

    public function options()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\Dcn\Store\Option', 'store_option_values', 'op-values_id', 'options_id');
    }
}
```

And Finally an Invoice Model:

```
class Invoice extends \Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'store_invoices';

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\Dcn\Store\Item', 'store_invoices_items', 'invoice_id', 'item_id');
    }
}
```

When a user checkout I currently create an invoice and attach the items, but I need to be able to store the options (color, size, etc) for each item in the invoice.

I'm just not sure what the best way to store the values for the Items's options in the invoice because a user could have multiple items that are just different colors. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution involves the following models/tables/relations:

#### Invoice

One To Many relation with InvoiceItems.

`Invoice->hasMany('InvoiceItem')`

---

#### InvoiceItem

This model contains the line items for each invoice, with `invoice_id` (foreign key) linking the InvoiceItem to Invoice, and `item_id` linking the InvoiceItem to an Item from your inventory. (Other order details would be stored here as well, such as quantity of the item, etc.)

`InvoiceItem->belongsTo('Invoice')`

`InvoiceItem->belongsTo('Item')`

Then, to store the options chosen for each InvoiceItem and their values, there's a One To Many relation with InvoiceItemOption.

`InvoiceItem->hasMany('InvoiceItemOption')`

---

#### InvoiceItemOption

For each InvoiceItem (linked by `invoice_item_id`), this model stores 0, 1, or more options (linked from the Option model by `option_id`) and that option's value (linked from the Value model by `value_id`).

`InvoiceItemOption->belongsTo('InvoiceItem')`

`InvoiceItemOption->belongsTo('Option')`

`InvoiceItemOption->belongsTo('Value')`

---

#### Item

This contains your list of items, i.e. your inventory. It has a One to Many relation with InvoiceItem (i.e. each Item can appear on many InvoiceItems, and each InvoiceItem has one Item). Each item also has 0, 1, or more Options available to it, so it is linked through a Many To Many relation with Option.

`Item->hasMany('InvoiceItem')`

`Item->belongsToMany('Option')`

---

#### item_option

This is a pivot table, linking each Item to its available Options (with `item_id` and `option_id`)

---

#### Option

All the available options for all Items. Each option has 1 or more possible Values, and is linked through a Many To Many relation with Value

`Option->belongsToMany('Item')`

`Option->belongsToMany('Value')`

---

#### option_value

This is a pivot table, linking each Option to its available Values (with `option_id` and `value_id`).

---

#### Value

All the available values for all Options.

`Value->belongsToMany('Option')`

---

For each relation, I've defined the inverse relation as well, which would give you maximum flexibility. Depending on your needs, though, some of those inverse relations might be unnecessary.

---

There are two other alternatives, neither of which I think are good ones:

You could link Invoices and Items via a Many To Many relation (as you've done), and store your invoice line item information in the intermediate `invoice_item` pivot table. To do this, though, you would need to create a custom pivot model (rather than a simple pivot table), since that model would need to have a `hasMany('InvoiceItemOption')` relation to store the selected options and values. This would limit your flexibility somewhat in how you interact with the InvoiceItem model, and there's nothing really to be gained by this approach.

(But, if your interested in a good example of how to set up such a custom pivot model, see https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2093#issuecomment-39154456.)

A third and even less optimal option would be to link Invoices and Items via a Many To Many relation, and store the options and values in a serialized form in the intermediary `invoice_item` pivot table, along with any other order details like quantity. To do this, you would need to specify the extra fields when you define the Invoice relation:

`$this->belongsToMany('Items')->withPivot('quantity', 'options_serialized')->withTimestamps();`

This method is very inflexible, though—running a query for orders containing extra-large green shirts, for example, would be a pain.